# Почему после установки westen отсутствует файл конфигурации?

Tags: ubuntu, wayland

После установки westen на ubuntu хотел сконфигурировать , но по пути `/ect/westen.ini`  файла не обнаружено, поиск по папке тоже ни к чему не привел.

Объясните, может что-то я не так делаю?

Если конкретизировать, то цель развернуть окно приложения на 90 градусов.

Answer (score 0):

судя по ману он должен быть расположен в одном из этих мест:

> Weston uses a configuration file called weston.ini for its setup. The
> weston.ini configuration file is searched for in one of the following
> places when the server is started:
>
> ```
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/weston.ini   (if $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is set)
> $HOME/.config/weston.ini      (if $HOME is set)
> weston/weston.ini in each
>     $XDG_CONFIG_DIR           (if $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is set)
> /etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini    (if $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is not set)
> ```
>
> where environment variable $HOME is the user's home directory, and
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is the user specific configuration directory, and
> $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is a colon ':' delimited listed of configuration base
> directories, such as /etc/xdg-foo:/etc/xdg.

если там не найдётся то просто создайте файл `~/.config/weston.ini` и пропишите в нём то что вам нужно

вот пример минимальной конфигурации:

```
[core]
xwayland=true

[keyboard]
keymap_layout=gb

[output]
name=LVDS1
mode=1680x1050
transform=rotate-90

[launcher]
icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/24x24/apps/utilities-terminal.png
path=/usr/bin/weston-terminal

[launcher]
icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/firefox.png
path=/usr/bin/firefox
```

детальнее смотри [weston.ini.5](https://man.archlinux.org/man/weston.ini.5) и [Weston#Configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Weston#Configuration)

Comment: на всей машине есть только архив с упоминанием конфига. usr/share/man/man5/weston.ini.5.gz

Comment: @Amos, это архив с маном; значит просто создайте свой конфиг по указанному выше пути `~/.config/weston.ini`